# Change content of UITableViewCell based on orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` which displays attributes for an NSArray of custom types. When in portrait orientation I want to show three labels (to act like columns) but when in landscape I can fit more on the `UITableViewCell` and I'd like to show 5 labels.

Currently I am laying out my portrait cells on a prototype cell in the storyboard editor by putting `UILabels` on a `UITableViewCell` and giving tagging them so that I can get to the subviews and set the text in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. I started down this road for easy use of the auto layout of my labels.

I have found lots of suggestions to re-size/move items on a cell when orientation changes but not how I can change the number of subviews visible. I was thinking of trying to use two different cell identifiers (one with more labels for landscape mode) and choosing which one I want based on `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation`. I guess would also need to force reload of cells on rotation.

Is there an easier/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just develop 2 different prototypes with unique identifiers, provide them in cellForRowAtIndexPath based on current orientation.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {

        LatestNewsCell *cell = (LatestNewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"portraitCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // configure cell

        return cell;

    } else {

        LatestNewsCell *cell = (LatestNewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"landscapeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // configure cell

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In the case of the cell with more labels, you just create additional IBOutlets for these and reuse the existing ones for the labels that are used in both orientations.

Edit: Do reload table on the orientation change.

Answer (score 1):

You could swap the entire data source and delegate, or even the entire view on orientation change. Depending on how much you have to configure, that could make your code a lot cleaner. Apple has a nice guide on this here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW14

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought about swapping out the whole View Controller. It would make the layout cleaner but I will end up having to maintain two classes rather than one, and avoiding duplicating code between the two VCs will be hard.

Comment: Even worse if you have duplicated code in an if-else statement! You should really calculate how much duplicated code you could save. If there is too much, maybe you should think about further separating some logic from the VCs into some other class (maybe your view controllers are performing data model tasks?)

Answer (score 0):

Another option on this is a UICollectionViewController. Tables in UIkit are made for one single column, whereas collectionViews are for more complex layouts like the one you want to achieve.